# how to make background-image included via a "class" responsive

Tags: html, css, svg

I have the following codepen - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PPLeRV?editors=110

I create a SVG sprite - from icomoon and use it as a background image class. I need to know how to make it responsive.

html

```
<a class="icon icon-home" href="#"></a>
<a class="icon icon-books" href="#"></a>
<a class="icon icon-folder-open" href="#"></a>
<a class="icon icon-location2" href="#"></a>
```

css

```
.icon {
    display: inline-block;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: url(http://imgh.us/sprite_4.svg);
}
.icon-home {
    width: 96px;
    height: 96px;
    background-position: 0 0;
}
.icon-play {
    width: 96px;
    height: 96px;
    background-position: -112px 0;
}
.icon-clubs {
    width: 96px;
    height: 96px;
    background-position: -224px 0;
}
.icon-books {
    width: 108px;
    height: 96px;
    background-position: -336px 0;
}
.icon-folder-open {
    width: 96px;
    height: 96px;
    background-position: -560px 0;
}
.icon-location2 {
    width: 96px;
    height: 96px;
    background-position: -672px 0;
}
```

Unfortunately - when I use these images it does not work well for different media types. I can use media queries - but the zoom function does not work well.

I am using this function to reduce http request - sprite and all, instead of individual images url.

I tried putting them in a flex box - and div etc - but it does not respond.

help :)

Comment: Hi there. What you can do is make it a vertical sprite sheet and then once you position your sprite correctly using background position you can set the background size 100% auto. This would require making your containers a percentage base width that would scale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qOvKdy)

Use background-size and height with relative unit like I'm using vw

```
1vw = 1% of viewport width
```

When the browser resizes your height (in vw), it changes according to the browser width. It supports Major Browser : Firefox, Chrome but I don't know about IE

```css
.icon {
  display: inline-block;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image: url("http://imgh.us/sprite_4.svg");
  border: 1px solid grey;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20vw;
  max-width: 10%;
  background-size: 80vw 20vw;
}
.icon-home {
  background-position: left -1% bottom 0px;
}
.icon-books {
  background-position: left 43% bottom 0px;
}
.icon-folder-open {
  background-position: left 72% bottom 0px;
}
.icon-location2 {
  background-position: left 87% bottom 0px;
}
```

```html
<a class="icon icon-home" href="#"></a>
<a class="icon icon-books" href="#"></a>
<a class="icon icon-folder-open" href="#"></a>
<a class="icon icon-location2" href="#"></a>
```

Comment: how did you create the "background-position" with 1%, 43% etc ?

Comment: background-position can be given in px ,%, and you can value of its as left top, left bottom .. etc . So using relative unit was to make it responsive to browser

Comment: I mean how did you know to use thoses values ? I used icomoon - and it generated the px values. how did you convert them to % value ? if I change the spite - how can I generate those % values

Comment: Infact - I am not able to understand how you took  "    width: 96px;
    height: 96px;
    background-position: -672px 0;" and converted it to "  background-position: left 87% bottom 0px;
"

Comment: for width 96px i have set max-width:10%in icon class that restrict its size to 10% of sprite image

Comment: @hypermails if your sprite has same size and all icons are also same size in similar to the current sprite it will work but if its not then you have do trial and error and check if its fitting within each anchor tag.

Comment: ok - will be honest - your solution works as expected - but I don't understand how you converted the sprite mapping to your way of mapping the icons using "left some% bottom some px"  - can you be a little more clearer in how you did that. - thx

Comment: there no mapping such Percentage is relative to parent i.e When the parent (sprite image )width is 800px then 50% would become 400px so you have to calculate on your own and then try  this how i did when i saw sprite image for background-position: left  43% i.e 43% of 880 =378.3 you don't have to specify negative sign here i think for books you have taken 336px and mine is 378 some what close but percentage is making  relative to browser . I hope you get it

Answer (score 0):

use `background-size` with media queries. An example is given below.

I added the following codes to your css. And it worked for me.

```
* {
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    margin: 0;
    outline: 0;
}
@media screen and (max-width:450px) {
    .icon {
        background-size: 100vw 11vw;
    }
    .icon-home, .icon-play, .icon-clubs, .icon-books, .icon-folder-open, .icon-location2 {
        width: 11vw;
        height: 11vw;
    }
    .icon-home {
        background-position: 0 0;
    }
    .icon-play {
        background-position: -14vw 0;
    }
    .icon-clubs {
        background-position: -27vw 0;
    }
    .icon-books {
        background-position: -41vw 0;
    }
    .icon-folder-open {
        background-position: -64vw 0;
    }
    .icon-location2 {
        background-position: -78vw 0;
    }
}
```

HTML

```
<a class="icon icon-home" href="#"></a>
<a class="icon icon-books" href="#"></a>
<a class="icon icon-folder-open" href="#"></a>
<a class="icon icon-location2" href="#"></a>
```

Note: I remove any default margin, padding, border and outline by using

Comment: how did you come up with the sprite values ?

Comment: @hypermails Using Box Model in Inspect Element in Firefox, I know that the total width of your image as 880px. For width, 96px/880px = 10.9. Also for position, 120px/880px = 13.6. And I rounded the fraction..